# Gujarati font for Corel draw

Tags: photo-editing, corel-draw

I'm using Corel draw.

Recently when I try to type in our local language "Gujarati" via Google Input tools or font installation with Gujarati fonts, the typed text is not showing joined words and characters correctly.

Comment: if you're using coreldraw why tag the question with photoshop and illustrator?

Comment: I've removed these tags, since they are not appropriate.

Comment: @Steave - fonts are not really created for specific software. You might want to check your Corel Draw documentation to see if it has support for South Asian languages. Failing that, contact Corel for technical support.

Answer (score 2):

This is a ligature issue. CorelDRAW X4 & X5 doesn't have full ligatures support. Full ligatures (or open type) support was added in CorelDRAW X6.

You need to upgrade to CorelDRAW X6 otherwise for X4/X5 you'll have to use third party language softwares like Akruti, Shreelipi etc.

You should check for more info in a coreldraw community support [like this](https://community.coreldraw.com/talk/coreldraw_graphics_suite_x4/f/coreldraw-graphics-suite-x4/37341/gujrati-fonts-problem-in-corel-draw-x4).